# net-logo grid and accuracy, how do i divide the patches to make my map more accurate

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to increase the number of patches in my project and make them smaller, I need patch size to be smaller because I'm using very specific xy coordinates and if I have 2 points near each-other on the same patch they overlap (I'm calling my turtles to specific patches where the points intersect) and i want the points to have more "breathing room" and even though some points are close to each other i want them to at least not be so clustered in one patch.
I've tried the edit patch size but it only seems to change the size of the simulation view. and if I had more patches I could more accurately call the turtles as they'll intersect with the points better(as of now a single patch takes a large portion of my map(its dense) and the points are from a gis layer.

Comment: Have a look at the section [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) on 2D and 3D views- the settings you probably want to change are `max-pxcor` and `max-pycor`. These settings (and sometimes `min-pxcor` and `min-pycor` if you change your location of origin) define the number of cells in your world.